# Call view in Laravel Controller with anchor tag

Tags: laravel

I need to call a view in a Laravel Controller, with parameters and with Anchor Tag.
I have this code in my controller:

```
return view('plans/editPlanView',
    ['plan' => $plan,
    'patient' => $patient,
    'aliments'=>$aliments, 'menu'=>$menu, 'tabName'=>$tabName]);
```

But i need to add an Anchor tag to land in a specific section of the page.
I can't use

```
return Redirect::to(URL::previous() . "#whatever");
```

proposed in other posts because i need to pass some parameters.

I think there are some base problem, trying with console this:

```
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#whatever').offset().top
 }, 1000);
```

scrolling to the desired section does not work.
it seems the page makes a small snap but always returns to the top.

**Update**

I have found the cause of the problem. At the bottom of the blade page I have the following code, without it the anchor tag works fine. Adding it the page makes a small scroll to return to the head. I need to use the datepicker, how can I fix the problem and get the anchor tag to work?

```
@push('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {            
            $('.date').datepicker({
                firstDayOfWeek: 1,
                weekDayFormat: 'narrow',
                inputFormat: 'd/M/y',
                outputFormat: 'd/M/y',
                markup: 'bootstrap4',
                theme: 'bootstrap',
                modal: false
            });
        });
    </script>
@endpush
```

Comment: the only way to get that fragment into the URL is if there was a link with it in it already, or you would need to do a redirect with it in the URL, it has to be provided with the request, you can't add it via a response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect back to a specific tab pane in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747262/redirect-back-to-a-specific-tab-pane-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the method `showPage()` in your contoller for example `TestController`

```
public function showPage(Request $request)
{
    $plan = $request->plan;
    ...

    return view('plans/editPlanView', [
        'plan' => $plan,
        'patient' => $patient,
        'aliments'=>$aliments, 'menu'=>$menu, 'tabName'=>$tabName
    ]);
}
```

Then create a route for rendering that view

```
Route::get('/someurl', 'TestController@showPage')->name('show-page');
```

And then in your methods you can use something like that:

```
$url = URL::route('show-page', ['#whatever']);
return Redirect::to($url)
```

Comment: And how can i pass parameters in showPage() method?

Comment: I edited my answer, if I understand you right

Comment: does not works. I have updated my post, i this there are some base problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, I added the disable attribute to the date input, in doing so, when the datepicker is initialized, the page does not scroll up. Then, as a last javascript statement I re-enabled the fields:

```
$('.date').prop("disabled", false);
```